# Postgres Select Query: SELECT number of appearance in two other tables

Tags: postgresql

I want to select the total number of appearance of a single player in two other tables.

Here is my database structure (postgres):

```
Table: Player
id              integer

Table: World Champions
id              integer
year            date
player_id       integer

Table: European Champions
id              integer
year            date
player_id       integer
```

The id on table player is also available in table "World Champions" and "European Champions" (player_id).
I want to select the data as following:

```
player.id       worldChampionTitles     europeanChampionTitles
1               3                       4
2               1                       0
3               0                       0
4               1                       1
```

But I have no Idea how to write my select query for that.

Comment: Left join your tables on player_id  and use player.id as grouping field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with subqueries:

```
SELECT p.id
     , (SELECT count(*) FROM "World Champions" AS c WHERE c.player_id = p.id)
         + (SELECT count(*) FROM "European Champions" AS c WHERE c.player_id = p.id)
FROM Player AS p
```